# Como iniciar uma chamada do skype a partir de uma ação no navegador?

Tags: html, skype

Preciso adicionar um botão de "suporte on-line" na minha pagina mas em vez de criar um chat on-line gostaria de usar o Skype.

Qual a melhor maneira de se implementar isso?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a **Skype URI**

No lugar da url você passa um comando que será entendido pelo navegador como a execução de uma instrução em um aplicativo externo

```html
<a href='skype:echo123?chat&topic=Teste'>Abrir conversa</a>

<a href='skype:echo123?call&topic=Assunto'>Iniciar chamada</a>
```

Nos exemplos acima, **echo123** é o contato do skype, **chat** / **call** é o tipo de ação que o skype irá executar e **topic** é o assunto da chamada.

Você pode ver mais exemplo na pagina do [skype](http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/skype-uri-tutorial-webpages)

O navegador irá exibir uma janela de dialogo pedindo autorização para iniciar o aplicativo. Algo semelhante ao que acontece quando você clica no link magnético de um torrent, somente após isso o skype será iniciado.